# Compound logical tests in bash

Tags: bash, testing

A question about bash ....

I wrote a little code to check whether a year is a leapyear.  The relevant part looks like:

```
if [ $testnum4 -eq 0 -a $testnum100 -ne 0 ] || [ $testnum400 -eq 0 ]
then
  echo 0
fi
```

Well, this code actually works.  My problem is that I'm still not quite sure what I was doing.  Just to see what would happen, I have tried several variations on this: enclosing the entire test expression in square backets, using `&&` where I have `-a` and `-o` where I have `||`, etc.  Nothing works except for the one expression that I wrote above.  I stumbled on it, and I'm glad I did, but the next time I have to do something like this, I would like to know what I am doing.

So: Anyone have a quick explanation of how compound tests work in bash?  or a pointer to a good resource on this topic?

Thanks.

Here's a code that failed:

```
let testnum4=$1%4
let testnum100=$1%100
let testnum400=$1%400

if [ $testnum4 -eq 0 && $testnum100 -ne 0 ] -o [ $testnum400 -eq 0 ]
then
  echo 0
fi
```

Comment: Your code does not run. `[ $testnum4 -eq 0 -a $testnum100 -ne 0 ]` results in a syntax error in both bash and sh.

Comment: @CodeGnome: you do realise, that it expects some variables to be set? :)

Comment: @bob.sacamento: post the code that you thought was correct but didn't work... then we can help..

Comment: Ummm, maybe I should have put the whole code in.  I thought people whould only be interested in the part relevant to the question.  But I have run the full code successfully on my linux desktop about 25 times now. Sorry for any confusion I've cause. Here's an example of something that didn't work:

Comment: Whoops.  I'm new here.  Didn't realize what the return key would do.  Will provide example in an answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Little note of interest: The square braces are actually a Unix command. See if there's a file called `/bin/[` or `/usr/bin/[` on your system. In fact, try this:

```
$ ls i-il /bin[ /bin/test
571541 -r-xr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  43120 Aug 17  2011 /bin/[
571541 -r-xr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  43120 Aug 17  2011 /bin/test
```

That first number is the i-node number. You see that `/bin/[` and `/bin/test` are hard linked to each other. They're the same program.

I'll get back to the significance of this a bit later...

---

In BASH and other Bourne type shells, the `if` command merely runs the command, and if the command returns an exit code of `0`, it executes the commands in the `if` clause. If the command does not return an exit code of `0`, it skips the commands in the `if` clause and executes the commands in the `else` clause if it exists.

Thus, this is also valid:

```
if sleep 2
then
   echo "That was a good nap!"
fi
```

Your computer executes the `sleep 2` command which (if the sleep command exists) will return a zero exit code and continue to echo *That was a good nap!*.

That's all the `if` command really does. It runs the given command and examines the exit code.

---

Now, back to the `[`...

You might want to look at the manpage for the [test](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/test/) command. You can see that the `test` command seems to have many of the same type of tests as the `[...]` in the if statement. In fact, in the original Bourne shell (which BASH is derived from) these are the same command structure:

```
if test -f $my_file
then
    echo "File $my_file exists"
else
    echo "There is no file $my_file"
fi

if [ -f $my_file ]
then
    echo "File $my_file exists"
else
    echo "There is no file $my_file"
fi
```

In fact, in the original Bourne shell, you had to use the `test` command and not the square brackets.

---

So, back to your original question. The `-a` and `-o` are parameters for the test command (see the `test` manpage. For example, your `if` statement could have been written as this:

```
if test $testnum4 -eq 0 -a $testnum100 -ne 0 || test $testnum400 -eq 0
then
   echo 0
fi
```

However, the `&&` and `||` are not test command parameters, so they can't be used inside the test command.

Note that `[` is a built in command in BASH, so BASH does not execute `/bin/[` as the original Bourne shell would have. However, it is still a command much like `echo` is a built in command in BASH although `/bin/echo` also still exists.

Comment: An encyclopedic answer!  Thanks, David W.

Comment: This is seriously a stupendous answer. I've been trying to wrap my head around these `if` blocks for a while. Now it all makes sense.

Comment: I love that flow. in the answer. :)

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to do integer comparisons in Bash is to use double parentheses:

```
if (( (testnum4 == 0 && testnum100 != 0) || testnum400 == 0 ))
```

Answer (score 1):

### The Algorithm

The algorithm to check for leap years is (in pseudo code):

```
if (YEAR modulo 400):
    LEAP_YEAR = true
elseif (YEAR modulo 4) and not (YEAR modulo 100):
    LEAP_YEAR = true
else
    LEAP_YEAR = false
endif
```

I'd recommend against using over-clever solutions, and stick with something more readable. See the [Bash Beginner's Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_02.html#sect_07_02_03) for a working example of a leap year test using nested if statements. It uses the deprecated `$[]` arithmetic expression, so just replace the arithmetic expressions with `$(( ))` and you can see how it's supposed to work.

### How the OPs Code Works

In the OPs updated code example, the values are separate variables built from a positional paramater. So, the modulo arithmetic is being performed on the variables before they are evaluated in the conditional statements. After that, the if statement says:

```
if (first_expression returns true) or (second_expression returns true):
    echo 0
endif
```

The single-square brackets are simply a shell builtin that performs the same as the `test` command, which evaluates an expression and returns an exit status where zero is truth. See `help \[` or `man test` for more information.

### Building a Better Mousetrap

While I and other posters have explained why the OPs code works, it seems that part of the OPs goal is to place the entire leap year test inside a single conditional. Here's a Bash shell function that will do this, and let you test the result by inspecting the exit status.

```
# function returns exit status of arithmetic expression
leap_year () { 
    (( $1 % 400 == 0 || ($1 % 4 == 0 && $1 % 100 != 0) ))
}
```

You can test the function at the prompt:

```
$ leap_year 2011; echo $?
1
$ leap_year 2012; echo $?
0
$ leap_year 2013; echo $?
1
```

For more information on the `(( ))` arithmetic expression, see the [Conditional Constructs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs) sections of the Bash Reference Manual.

Comment: Thanks very much CodeGnome.  Much obliged.

Comment: I'd like to add that now you can do `if leap_year 2012;then echo "do something" ; fi` with the above solution.

Answer (score 0):

In bash(actually most shells) `if` takes a command/set of commands and evaluates the `then` section if the last command returns true (zero exit code), otherwise it evaluates the `elif`/`else` sections (`elif` is treated in a manner similar to else).

Now about the `[[`. This is like the `test` command, but with greater test coverage. However it has the limitation that it can evaluate only one condition at a time, so it **doesn't** accept **-o** or **-a**. You might want to look at `[` as a true alias of `test`. As for the `||` and `&&` these are control operators that evaluate the next command if the previous command returns false (non-zero exit code) or true (zero exit code) respectively. The use of these 2 is to chain commands together (especially `[[`).

As for the above if, it executes 2 commands:

- First: `[ $testnum4 -eq 0 -a $testnum100 -ne 0 ]`
- Second: `[ $testnum400 -eq 0 ]`

If the first command succeeds, the if executes the `then` section. If the first command fails, then the second is executed. If the second succeeds, then the body is executed, else `if` does nothing.

As for a good bash resource, you might want to visit [The Bash Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/doku.php)

Comment: OK, this is making more sense.  Thanks.  What if things get more complicated and I have to, for instance, nest some conditionals?  Can that be handled with && and || ?  Thanks again.

Comment: The usage of `||` and `&&` is somewhat tricky, and needs to be well thought out before creating the conditions. Look at the bash wiki for all the details.

Comment: Your second paragraph is confusing and incorrect. The double brackets are preferred in Bash over the single bracket form.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: I didn't mention anything about preference of `[` over `[[`, just that `[` is a true alias of `test` while `[[` is similar to test in spirit, but differs in the fact that it tests only one condition at a time and multiple conditions are tested by chaining them with `&&` and `||`.